# Flutter: How to extract a function for re-use in multiple screens

Tags: function, flutter, promise, extract

I have an onBackPressed() function that displays an AlertDialog and returns a Future depending on user's choice by pressing EXIT or CANCEL buttons. Here's the code:

```
// BACK PRESSED BUTTON HANDLER (FUNCTION)
Future<bool> onBackPressed() {
  return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          actionsPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 18, bottom: 10),
          // title: Text('Are you sure?'),
          content: Text('Do you want to exit the application?'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
              child: Text("CANCEL"),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 20),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
              child: Text("EXIT"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ) ??
      false;
}
```

I need to use this function in multiple screens to handle onBackPressed events with the  help of the WillPopScope widget, like this:

```
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: onBackPressed,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar( ...etc.
```

I tried to extract the function in a separate file but I get a problem with a missing context, required by showDialog.

How can I handle this? I feel that I missed some rather basic concepts but nevertheless would be grateful for anybody helping me in the right direction.

Comment: add one param `BuildContext context` to `_onBackPressed` and call it like: `onWillPop: () => _onBackPressed(context),`?

Comment: Please note that I had to change _onBackPressed() to non-private onBackPressed() function in the above code in order to import it from a separate file and use it in different places. – CEO tech4lifeapps 52 mins ago    Delete

Comment: @pskink  Your comment, particularly `onWillPop: () => onBackPressed(context),` solved my problem!

Comment: yep, good to hear that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass context to your function as

```
Future<bool> _onBackPressed(BuildContext context) {
    ...
}
```

and use as

```
//inside build(context) => Widget;
  return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () => _onBackPressed(context),// context must be visible here
  child: ...
```

Comment: It seems I missed the lecture on the pattern used by `onWillPop: () => _onBackPressed(context)`.  Back to school!

Answer (score 1):

You missed to accept a context parameter, so you showDialog() doesn't know where to draw.

Something like this would do:

```
      Future<bool> _onBackPressed(BuildContext context) {
          return showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                  actionsPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 18, bottom: 10),
                  // title: Text('Are you sure?'),
                  content: Text('Do you want to exit the application?'),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                      child: Text("CANCEL"),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 20),
                    SizedBox(height: 16),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                      child: Text("EXIT"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ) ??
              false;
        }
```

And every time you call it pass the context of the widget.

> _onBackPressed(context)